# Replacing indefinite loop

Tags: java, loops, wait

I have a indefinite loop to test for messages in a queue:

```
     //main class
     boolean brun=true;

     while(brun) 
 {

      if(!queue.isEmpty()) //there's a new message 
      {
       msg=queue.remove(0);  //remove it from the queue
       nqueue--;
       //process the message
       if(msg==0)
       ...
       if(msg=999)
              brun=false; //exit
      }
     }
```

How can I use Condition.await() to suspend execution until queue is not empty?

Thank you for your help,
Pedro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking, but if you want to get an object from the queue and wait till the queue has an object to take, you can use [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

If you want to wait until the queue has an object use `queue.take()`. It will hang until the queue has an object, and remove it from the queue.